# Variable Behavior

Tags: shell-script, date

Before I start I'm not asking for any code to be written just to enlighten and the behavior I am having. I have this snippet of code.

```
NOW=$(date +"%H")
While [ true ]; do
 echo $NOW
done
```

I would of expected so that when it would be printed to the screen the time would update since I am storing the date command and formatting it into the variable NOW , but instead all it does is keep printing the same date that the script was started at. Will someone enlighten me on why it does that.

Comment: BTW, `while [ true ]` isn't doing what you think it is -- the `[ ]` command is checking the string "true" to see if it's non-blank, and since it is it returns true. But `while [ false ]`, `while [ wibble ]` etc would all *also* return true (and hence run the loop forever). It makes much more sense to use `while true` -- without the `[ ]`, around it `true` is interpreted as a command, and there is a command named `true` that always succeeds (i.e. returns true). (Compare with `while false`, which runs the command `false`, which always fails/returns false.)

Answer (score 3):

It behaves as it should. What you expect, could be achieved this way:

```
while [ true ]; do
    NOW=$(date +"%H")
    echo $NOW
done
```

Now the variable is updated at each iteration of the loop.

Compare both with this one:

```
NOW=date

while [ true ]; do
    $NOW
done
```

Here date is recalculated at each iteration, as the command itself is stored in the variable, not its result.

Comment: Hmm. I thought though since date is not static, that it would of changed every time it was called regardless of where the variable is stored since the i would call $NOW which would call date with the current time. I guess it doesn't pull information like that. Behaves differently than other languages I've used. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: See the update above.

Comment: @tomas how would `$NOW` be used with `+"%H"` ?  Maybe worth updating your example with this.

Answer (score 2):

A *variable* is given a value when it is assigned.

For example

```
x=1
```

will set the value of the variable `x` to 1.  The value doesn't change unless you assign a new value to it.

When you do

```
NOW=$(date +"%H")
```

then the shell will run the `date` command and put the results into the `NOW` variable.  Again, the value doesn't change unless you assign a new value.  It doesn't matter that `date` is an external command; it's run *once* when the variable is assigned the value.

So you either need to assign the value inside the loop... *or* use a function.

```
NOW()
{
   date +"%H"
}
```

This doesn't defined a variable, but a function.  You can now use this inside your loop

```
while [ true ]; do
  echo $(NOW)
done
```

Note that the way you call it is different.

In this limited case we can make it simpler:

```
while [ true ]; do
  NOW
done
```

So the final script would be

```
#!/bin/bash

NOW()
{
   date +"%H"
}

while [ true ]; do
  NOW
done
```